# java - arraylist.add function gets ignored if i add 2 or 3 after each other

Tags: java

So am fairly new to programming in general , and i wanted to make a simple student database system, using array lists and methods , thing is i have a problem with my add_inf() method where it ignores my first name.add(in.nextLine); and doesnt take any input for it
and goes straight to the second command
here is the full code:

```
package advanced.db;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AdvancedDb {

    static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    static ArrayList<String> st_name = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> age = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<String> address = new ArrayList<>();

public static void add_info(){

    System.out.print("enter Name :");
    st_name.add(in.nextLine());

    System.out.print("enter age :");
    age.add(in.nextLine());
    
    System.out.print("enter address :");
    address.add(in.nextLine());
        
    }

    public static void view() {
        for (int x = 0; x < st_name.size() && x < age.size() && x < address.size(); x++) {

            System.out.println(st_name.get(x));
            System.out.println(age.get(x));
            System.out.println(address.get(x) + "\t");

        }
        if (st_name.isEmpty() && age.isEmpty() && address.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("list is empty");
        }
    }

    public static void delete() {
        System.out.println("please enter the name you want to be deleted");
        String input;

        input = in.nextLine();
        for (int x = 0; x < st_name.size() && x < age.size() && x < address.size(); x++) {
            if (input.equals(st_name.get(x))) {
                System.out.println("info of the name (" + input + ")\n is deleted");
                st_name.remove(x);
                age.remove(x);
                address.remove(x);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void search() {
        System.out.println("enter the name or age you're searching for  ");
        String input;

        input = in.nextLine();
        for (int x = 0; x < st_name.size() && x < age.size() && x < address.size(); x++) {
            if (input.equals(st_name.get(x))) {
                System.out.println("INFO regarding " + input + "is found");
                System.out.println("name :" + st_name.get(x));
                System.out.println("age  :" + age.get(x));
                System.out.println("address :" + address.get(x));
            } else if (input.equals(age.get(x))) {
                System.out.println("students with the age (" + input + ")");
                System.out.println("name :" + st_name.get(x));
                System.out.println("age  :" + age.get(x));
                System.out.println("address :" + address.get(x) + "\t");
            } else {
                System.out.println("nothing is found regarding the input");
            }
        }
            if (st_name.isEmpty() && age.isEmpty() && address.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("list is empty");
            }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int x = 0;
        System.out.println("welcome\n\n");
        System.out.println("what do you want to do ");
        System.out.println("1-view the lsit of students ");
        System.out.println("2-add a new student");
        System.out.println("3-delete a student ");
        System.out.println("4-search for student ");
        System.out.println("5-exit \n");
        while (x == 0) {
            System.out.print("choice :");

             switch (in.nextInt()) {
                case 1:
                    view();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    add_info();
                  
                    break;
                case 3:
                    delete();
                    break;
                case 4:
                    search();
                    break;
                case 5:
                    x = 1;
                    System.out.println("exiting now");
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("incorrect input try again");
                    break;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

for some reason the output when you press 2 as your choice is
name:age:
address:
taking age and address only
i tried removing the name.add(in.nextLine) and left age and address it did the same thing ignoring age and taking address only
i would really appreciate it if someone helped me understand why this is happening

Comment: `in.nextInt()` command in your `main` method is reading the integer but not the newline generated by the user hitting 'return'. So the `in.nextLine()` is just returning the part of the line between the previous token (the integer) and the newline (i.e. nothing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Comment: [Comment by sprinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67463270/java-arraylist-add-function-gets-ignored-if-i-add-2-or-3-after-each-other#comment119242369_67463270) is correct. In other words, an unconsumed newline from user pressing `2` and hitting Return/Enter key was left pending. Your next line, `st_name.add(in.nextLine());` then consumes that pending newline, adding an empty string to your `st_name` array.